# Create Array From Attribute of NSObject From NSFetchResultsController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a NSFetchResultsController that fetches a NSObject.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"WeekDay" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
[fetchRequest setPredicate: predicate];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timeStamp" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
```

Usually I would get the data from this fetch like this:

```
 self.selectedWeekDay = (WeekDay *)[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

But what I need  is an array with all the timeStamps, in a format similar to

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"2011-11-01 00:00:00 +0000", @"2011-12-01 00:00:00 +0000", nil];
```

How can I do this?

Edit:

When I NSLog the array code you provided, it give this:

```
The content of data is(
        {
        timeStamp = "2011-06-14 21:30:03 +0000";
    },
        {
        timeStamp = "2011-06-16 21:00:18 +0000";
    },
        {
        timeStamp = "2011-06-11 21:00:18 +0000";
    },
        {
        timeStamp = "2011-06-23 19:53:35 +0000";
    },
        {
        timeStamp = "2011-06-21 19:53:35 +0000";
    }
)
```

Edit 2:

Tapuko Library Calendar Code:

```
- (NSArray*)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView marksFromDate:(NSDate *)startDate toDate:(NSDate *)lastDate {    
    NSLog(@"calendarMonthView marksFromDate toDate");   
    NSLog(@"Make sure to update 'data' variable to pull from CoreData, website, User Defaults, or some other source.");
    // When testing initially you will have to update the dates in this array so they are visible at the
    // time frame you are testing the code.
    NSArray *data = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     @"2011-01-01 00:00:00 +0000", @"2011-12-01 00:00:00 +0000", nil]; 


    // Initialise empty marks array, this will be populated with TRUE/FALSE in order for each day a marker should be placed on.
    NSMutableArray *marks = [NSMutableArray array];

    // Initialise calendar to current type and set the timezone to never have daylight saving
    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    [cal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

    // Construct DateComponents based on startDate so the iterating date can be created.
    // Its massively important to do this assigning via the NSCalendar and NSDateComponents because of daylight saving has been removed 
    // with the timezone that was set above. If you just used "startDate" directly (ie, NSDate *date = startDate;) as the first 
    // iterating date then times would go up and down based on daylight savings.
    NSDateComponents *comp = [cal components:(NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | 
                                                    NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) 
                                          fromDate:startDate];
    NSDate *d = [cal dateFromComponents:comp];

    // Init offset components to increment days in the loop by one each time
    NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [offsetComponents setDay:1];    


    // for each date between start date and end date check if they exist in the data array
    while (YES) {
        // Is the date beyond the last date? If so, exit the loop.
        // NSOrderedDescending = the left value is greater than the right
        if ([d compare:lastDate] == NSOrderedDescending) {
            break;
        }

        // If the date is in the data array, add it to the marks array, else don't
        if ([data containsObject:[d description]]) {
            [marks addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
        } else {
            [marks addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
        }

        // Increment day using offset components (ie, 1 day in this instance)
        d = [cal dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:d options:0];
    }

    [offsetComponents release];

    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:marks];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Core Data Snippets guide has exactly this scenario, titled ['Fetching specific property values'](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/fetchExpressions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008420-SW1).

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entity];
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[request setReturnsDistinctResults:NO]; //set to YES if you only want unique values of the property
[request setPropertiesToFetch :[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"timeStamp"]]; //name(s) of properties you want to fetch

// Execute the fetch.
NSError *error;
NSArray *objects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Comment: I already have a NSFetchResultsController though, so is there a way to just use that?

Comment: No. NSFetchResultsController is designed from the ground up to retrieve entities, and that's all it does.

Comment: Ok, I tried this and 1) requestedValue is not used,and 2)it doesn't seem to be fetching anything.

Comment: Edited to remove the copy & paste extra. It most definitely works. Try dumping the contents of the request in the debugger. If it doesn't return anything, then the property name you gave me (timeStamp) isn't correct.

Comment: Ok so it fetching something, but I think the format is not working with the Calendar I am using. See the format of Array data in original question, and compare to the NSLog output I just added.

Comment: Thats a different question. You asked how to get an array of property values out of Core Data, not how to format an date. Core Data doesn't do date formatting, it isn't a complete SQL database - you have to get your data out of the store (which this code does, it returns an array of NSDates), then you can format it. THAT subject is [covered extensively](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nsdateformatter?sort=votes&pagesize=50) on SO.

Comment: No, the format of the date is perfectly fine.  Its the format of the array that is not working.  The array should just have the date objects in it, not the `timeStamp = ` part before each date.  I think it has something to do with the fetch returning a dictionary type `[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];`?

Comment: There is no other publicly available method of getting that data out of a core data store. Your consuming code will just have to be aware that it is getting an array of dictionaries, each dictionary has a single Key of "timeStamp", and the value is an NSDate.

Comment: Hmm, thats strange, I'm using the Tapku Library's Calendar framework, which specifically says you can use core data to set the data array.  Can you check the new code I just posted and see if there is a way to do so? Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry dude, this is the _only_ way I know of to pull values (not entities) out of Core Data. I learned this documented-yet-impossible-to-find snippet from the Core Data guru at Apple (Adam Swift) during WWDC. Just because documentation says you can use data from xyz source (core data) doesn't mean that you won't have to massage the data first. It's trivial to create an enumerator to walk the dictionary and create a new Array which you can hand off to your calendar API. Mark this as "answered" and create another question about walking the dict and returning an array, you'll get several opts

Comment: Thanks, I did that.  I made the new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481504/return-nsarray-from-nsdictionary

Comment: Answered. You might want to read the Stack Overflow [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Some people on here take the whole "only 1 question per post!!1!1" thing pretty seriously. Depending on how much I've been fighting with my GF, I can be a pain as well :) Also, be sure you mark answers, that increases your rating and ensures others are more likely to help you.