# Return NSArray from NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a fetch that returns an array with dictionary in it of an attribute of a core data object.

Here is my previous question: [Create Array From Attribute of NSObject From NSFetchResultsController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481239/create-array-from-attribute-of-nsobject-from-nsfetchresultscontroller)

This is the fetch:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entity];
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[request setReturnsDistinctResults:NO]; //set to YES if you only want unique values of the property
[request setPropertiesToFetch :[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"timeStamp"]]; //name(s) of properties you want to fetch

// Execute the fetch.
NSError *error;
NSArray *objects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

When I log the NSArray `data`, I get this:

```
The content of data is(
        {
        timeStamp = "2011-06-14 21:30:03 +0000";
    },
        {
        timeStamp = "2011-06-16 21:00:18 +0000";
    },
        {
        timeStamp = "2011-06-11 21:00:18 +0000";
    },
        {
        timeStamp = "2011-06-23 19:53:35 +0000";
    },
        {
        timeStamp = "2011-06-21 19:53:35 +0000";
    }
)
```

What I want is an array with this format:

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"2011-11-01 00:00:00 +0000", @"2011-12-01 00:00:00 +0000", nil];'
```

Edit:

This is the method for which I want to replace the data array with my new data array:

```
- (NSArray*)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView marksFromDate:(NSDate *)startDate toDate:(NSDate *)lastDate {    
    NSLog(@"calendarMonthView marksFromDate toDate");   
    NSLog(@"Make sure to update 'data' variable to pull from CoreData, website, User Defaults, or some other source.");
    // When testing initially you will have to update the dates in this array so they are visible at the
    // time frame you are testing the code.
    NSArray *data = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     @"2011-01-01 00:00:00 +0000", @"2011-12-01 00:00:00 +0000", nil]; 


    // Initialise empty marks array, this will be populated with TRUE/FALSE in order for each day a marker should be placed on.
    NSMutableArray *marks = [NSMutableArray array];

    // Initialise calendar to current type and set the timezone to never have daylight saving
    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    [cal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

    // Construct DateComponents based on startDate so the iterating date can be created.
    // Its massively important to do this assigning via the NSCalendar and NSDateComponents because of daylight saving has been removed 
    // with the timezone that was set above. If you just used "startDate" directly (ie, NSDate *date = startDate;) as the first 
    // iterating date then times would go up and down based on daylight savings.
    NSDateComponents *comp = [cal components:(NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | 
                                                    NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) 
                                          fromDate:startDate];
    NSDate *d = [cal dateFromComponents:comp];

    // Init offset components to increment days in the loop by one each time
    NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [offsetComponents setDay:1];    


    // for each date between start date and end date check if they exist in the data array
    while (YES) {
        // Is the date beyond the last date? If so, exit the loop.
        // NSOrderedDescending = the left value is greater than the right
        if ([d compare:lastDate] == NSOrderedDescending) {
            break;
        }

        // If the date is in the data array, add it to the marks array, else don't
        if ([data containsObject:[d description]]) {
            [marks addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
        } else {
            [marks addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
        }

        // Increment day using offset components (ie, 1 day in this instance)
        d = [cal dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:d options:0];
    }

    [offsetComponents release];

    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:marks];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call [`valueForKey`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BBCIBCDJ) on the array object returned from the fetch request. That will in-turn call `valueForKey` on each object and return an array of all resulting values.

```
NSArray *timestamps = [objects valueForKey:@"timeStamp"];
```

Comment: That is awesome. I love KVC, and learn something new about it every day.

Comment: Thanks Anurag.  But for some reason the data is still not loading my calendar view.  Here is a pic showing 2 arrays, the bottom one loads the data fine and was supplied with the sample app.  The top one is mine and doesnt load data.  Is it because my timeStamps need to be at 000000 for the hour and time? http://www.box.net/shared/static/s27n3hmab6r11n633pmo.png

Comment: Actually, I just posted the method above for which this array will be apart of.  Maybe there is something there I can change so that the time 0000000 vs the time in my timeStamps doesnt make a difference?

Comment: @RyanR - KVC gives Cocoa a very solid foundation. I like how some other languages deal with collections using `map`, `reduce,` `filter`. For example, in Ruby the equivalent would be, `timestamps = objects.map { |object| object[:timestamp] }`. Hopefully Cocoa will incorporate these methods into NSArray, and maybe those other languages will adopt KVC. Wishful thinking :)

Comment: @Anurag: My favorite so far, other than what you just demonstrated, is the [collection operators](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE). Performing functions over a collection in a single line of code just rocks.

Comment: @RyanR - thanks for sharing that link on collection operators. I was totally unaware of them. Something new to learn everyday :)

Comment: @Anurag, no, I did you get a chance to look at the method I posted?  The only reason I can see that it wouldn't work is because the hour and time are not 000000.

Comment: Hmm I think its because the marks array that it is comparing it to has `[cal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];`.  So maybe I need to do that to my data array as well?

Comment: @Jon - I think it's because `startDate` has non-zero components for hour, minutes, etc. like you said, and your `data` array doesn't. To ignore the hour, minutes, seconds, I would modify the line specifying the date components to `NSDateComponents *comp = [cal components:(NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:startDate];`. Not sure what timezone will the returned date be in. But if the timezone used in your data array is not the same as what `NSDate *d = [cal dateFromComponents:comp];` gives you, then you'll need to adjust that too.

Comment: Hmm, I just tried that, but it doesn't seem to be working either.  The dots are not showing up on the calendar

Comment: @Jon - if you log the description of the date object `[d description]`, what timezone does it return? Do you see the date in your timezone or GMT?

Comment: I just did that and got `2011-05-29 00:00:00 +0000` for `[d description]`

Comment: I think I need to remove daylight savings from the tmestamps in my data array.

Answer (score 2):

The Fast Enumeration method:

```
NSMutableArray *data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:array.count];
for (NSDictionary *d in objects) {
  [data addObject:[d objectForKey:@"timeStamp"]];
}
```

The [Block enumerator](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/Short_Practical_Guide_Blocks/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009758) method:

```
NSMutableArray *data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:array.count];
[objects enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
  [data addObject:[obj objectForKey:@"timeStamp"]];
}];
```

Either way, 'data' contains just an array of NSDate instances.

Comment: can you check the comments in the other answer I posted to see if you know whats going on? Thanks.

Comment: @Jon, not sure what you mean, I don't see any new comments in your other question, or elsewhere in this question. Can you clarify?

Comment: On the answer that Anurag provided, we are discussing a problem that we cannot resolve.

Answer (score 0):

To get the type of array you want, you can do something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int n = 0; n < [data count]; n++) // data array 
 {  
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[[data objectAtIndex:n] valueForKey:@"timeStamp"] ,nil];
   if ([array count] != 0) {
    [newArray addObject:[array objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
  }
 [array release];
```

hope this will help you!!

~Manoj