# Cannot getting an Array from NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, arrays, ipad

I have a dictionary like below:

```
{
    76 =     (
                {
            language = en;
            optionid = 1;
            response = ffgh;
        }
    );
    74 =     (
                {
            language = en;
            optionid = 1;
            response = "Herbert S.B. Baraf, MD";
        }
    );
    75 =     (
                {
            language = en;
            optionid = 1;
            response = ffgh;
        }
    );
    73 =     (
                {
            language = en;
            optionid = 1;
            response = Excellent;
        }
    );
}
```

I am not getting the key value array from my dictionary using below code:

```
NSMutableArray *Array=[m_MutDictAnswers objectForKey:m_strRuleQuestion ];
```

While logging the Array is empty and the `m_strRuleQuestion` is `73`.

I don't know why I am getting an empty array.
In my json string `m_strRuleQuestion` is "73" , but when I edit the json to `m_strRuleQuestion` to 73, I am getting the correct array. I need to fix this issue with out editing the json string. Can any one help me.

Comment: this kind of thing is easier to figure out with a breakpoint in the debugger... po [ dict objectForKey @"72"]

Comment: [ dict objectForKey @"72"] also returns empty array

Comment: then try @73,[ dict allKeys]... in the debugger you don't have to recompile and you can figure out what is really going on

Comment: Is `73` supposed to be an `NSString` or an `NSNumber`?

Comment: How you build this dictionary? what is the rounded brackets? Array is specified via square brackets in JSON and modern ObjC

Comment: did you try allKeys? how about po [[[m_MutDictAnswers allKeys]objectAtIndex:0] className]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return NSArray from NSDictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481504/return-nsarray-from-nsdictionary)

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray *Array=[m_MutDictAnswers objectForKey@"73"]
```

try this and then check what are you getting.

Answer (score 0):

I thing this dictionary is in array first you get array may its index of 0 after that fetch dictionary array

```
NSString *string=[[[myarray objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"72"]objectForKey:@"language"];
```